# Otimização de Consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-select

Montei um série de SQL mas estou tendo dificuldade para gerar algo que estresse menos o servidor, peço ajuda de vocês.

Segue o SQL:

```
SELECT '2015-06-10 00:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 00 AND 01;
SELECT '2015-06-10 01:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 01 AND 02;
SELECT '2015-06-10 02:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 02 AND 03;
SELECT '2015-06-10 03:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 03 AND 04;
SELECT '2015-06-10 04:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 04 AND 05;
SELECT '2015-06-10 05:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 05 AND 06;
SELECT '2015-06-10 06:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 06 AND 07;
SELECT '2015-06-10 07:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 07 AND 08;
SELECT '2015-06-10 08:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 08 AND 09;
SELECT '2015-06-10 09:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 09 AND 10;
SELECT '2015-06-10 10:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 10 AND 11;
SELECT '2015-06-10 11:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 11 AND 12;
SELECT '2015-06-10 12:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 12 AND 13;
SELECT '2015-06-10 13:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 13 AND 14;
SELECT '2015-06-10 14:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 14 AND 15;
SELECT '2015-06-10 15:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 15 AND 16;
SELECT '2015-06-10 16:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 16 AND 17;
SELECT '2015-06-10 17:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 17 AND 18;
SELECT '2015-06-10 18:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 18 AND 19;
SELECT '2015-06-10 19:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 19 AND 20;
SELECT '2015-06-10 20:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 20 AND 21;
SELECT '2015-06-10 21:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 21 AND 22;
SELECT '2015-06-10 22:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 22 AND 23;
SELECT '2015-06-10 23:00:00' AS 'Hora', COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' FROM contato WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' AND HOUR(data_hora) BETWEEN 23 AND 00;
```

Comment: O campo `data_hora` é varchar?

Comment: O por que disto `'2015-06-10 23:00:00' AS 'Hora'`? Não seria melhor pegar a data armazenada no banco?

Comment: é varchar, mas está com as informações em formato timestamp Ex. "2015-06-09 08:15:02"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fiz isso porque preciso criar uma exibição de quantidade por hora, montei um for para gerar o loop de cada horário.

Comment: Sim moises, mas isto poderia ser feito na camada do PHP, você também poderia usar apenas um `SELECT` e `OR` e na camada do PHP organizar os dados. Com certeza assim iria optimizar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Realmente tentei fazer, mas não consegui. Fiz uma execução em loop para listar.  Se poder me ajudar ficar muito grato.

Comment: No momento não tenho como por um exemplo pois estou no celular, assim que puder eu posto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado, ira ajudar muito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes tentar

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(data_hora, 1, 13) + '00:00' AS 'Hora', 
        COUNT(id_contato) AS 'Total' 
FROM contato 
WHERE data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, data_hora), 1, 13)
```

Caso na tua tabela tenhas os seguintes dados

```
DATA_HORA                  ID
'2015-06-10 21:01:01:000'  1
'2015-06-10 22:05:01:000'  2
'2015-06-10 22:12:01:000'  3
```

Este será o output

```
Hora                 Total
2015-06-30 21:00:00  1
2015-06-30 22:00:00  2
```

Caso queiras que no resultado sejam apresentadas todas as horas, mesmo aquelas para as quais não existem registos precisas de uma especie de tabela "Calendário". Segue um exemplo que produz, aquilo que penso, seja o resultado que desejas. É apenas um "proof of concept", para mostrar que é possível efectuar a operação do lado da base de dados e sinceramente, é rebuscado demais, de tal forma que não aconselharia o seu uso.

```
SELECT  CONCAT('2015-06-10 ', Horas.Hora, ':00:00') as Hora, COALESCE(COUNT(id_contacto), 0) Total
FROM (
  SELECT '00' Hora  UNION SELECT '01' UNION SELECT '02' UNION SELECT '03' UNION SELECT '04' UNION
  SELECT '05' UNION SELECT '06' UNION SELECT '07' UNION SELECT '08' UNION SELECT '09' UNION
  SELECT '10' UNION SELECT '11' UNION SELECT '12' UNION SELECT '13' UNION SELECT '14' UNION
  SELECT '15' UNION SELECT '16' UNION SELECT '17' UNION SELECT '18' UNION SELECT '19' UNION
  SELECT '20' UNION SELECT '21' UNION SELECT '22' UNION SELECT '23'
) Horas
LEFT JOIN contatos C
  ON SUBSTRING(C.data_hora, 12, 2) = Horas.Hora
 AND C.data_hora LIKE '2015-06-10%' 
GROUP BY CONCAT('2015-06-10 ', Horas.Hora, ':00:00')
ORDER BY 1
```

Com esta query e para os mesmos dados do exemplo anterior, o output sera:

```
Hora                Total
2015-06-10 00:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 01:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 02:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 03:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 04:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 05:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 06:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 07:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 08:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 09:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 10:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 11:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 12:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 13:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 14:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 15:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 16:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 17:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 18:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 19:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 20:00:00 0 
2015-06-10 21:00:00 1 
2015-06-10 22:00:00 2 
2015-06-10 23:00:00 0
```

Comment: Respondemos a mesma coisa ao mesmo tempo. Sua resposta ficou mais top.

Comment: @bruno Obrigado pela resposta, mas preciso que seja exibido também caso o resultado seja 0. Saberia me dizer como ? Valeu.

Comment: Queres dizer que, mesmo que não existam registos para determinada hora queres que a hora seja representada nos resultados com Total = 0?

Comment: Sim exatamente. Pode ser feito no SQL direto, ou trato no PHP?

Comment: Sim, pode ser feito no SQL. Dá-me uns minutos que eu actualizo a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, fico no aguardo

Comment: Imagina que na tua tabela não existe a data '2015-06-10', deverá ser apresentado algum resultado? Ou apenas serão apresentados resultados para as datas em que exista pelo menos um resultado (pelo menos um id_contacto)?

Comment: O que seria o ideal para seria.
Neste exemplo

Hora: 2015-06-09 01:00:00 - Total:0,
Hora: 2015-06-09 02:00:00 - Total:0,
Hora: 2015-06-09 03:00:00 - Total:1,
Hora: 2015-06-09 04:00:00 - Total:0,
Hora: 2015-06-09 05:00:00 - Total:4,
Hora: 2015-06-09 06:00:00 - Total:0,

Veja se consegue entender, obrigado.

Comment: @bruno Obrigado pela ajuda, era exatamente o que eu precisava.